# Iterate through MySql to ListView in Android

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview, loops

I wrote an Android App that pulls data from a MySql Database on a remote web server. The information is parsed and displayed in a listview. The listview also displays images which could slow down the activity. I was wondering how I could only display items 0-9, then when you click a button it will display 10-19, and so on. I can do it in VB using "do until" but as far as android/java, I am kind of lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the class where I need to implement it. I believe I would need to add an Integer to keep count and implement a form of "DO UNTIL" before I loop through the array and add a count to the "Integer" but I am not sure how to go about it here.

```
class ProductQuery extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... file_url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
            //Settings to send to PHP
            List<NameValuePair> settings = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //Adding Search Criteria(Keyword) to settings
            settings.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product", product));

            //Getting JSON result from request
            JSONObject jObject = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_to_php, "GET", settings);

            //Display JSON in LogCat
            Log.d("Product Search", jObject.toString());

            //Get Result 
            int result = jObject.getInt(KEY_RESULT);

            //If Result Equals 1 then
            if(result==1){
                //Getting the KEY_PRODUCTS
                products = jObject.getJSONArray(KEY_PRODUCTS);

                //Loop through Array

                for(int i = 0; i < products.length();i++){
                    JSONObject x = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    String proPid = x.getString(KEY_PRODID);
                    String name = x.getString(KEY_NAME);
                    String price = x.getString(KEY_PRICE);
                    String desc = x.getString(KEY_DESCRIPTION);
                    String img = x.getString(KEY_IMAGE);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmap.put(KEY_PRODID, proPid);
                    hmap.put(KEY_NAME, name);
                    hmap.put(KEY_PRICE, price);
                    hmap.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, desc);
                    hmap.put(KEY_IMAGE, img);

                    //Hash to ArrayList
                    myproducts.add(hmap);
}

            } else {


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: If you kept track of the page as an integer, then limit the for loop based on that.  You'd need to do some logic to check that the 10 items displayed in the page didn't breach products.length(), but that should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making pagination in the app, you should leave this to the server.

On your server, you should change the way you receive requests, so that when you call your server, you post a start index to fetch rows from and how many rows you want fetched for each request.

So the url to the server could look like this:

```
http://example.com/myjsonrequest.php?startindex=10&numofrows=10
```

In your PHP `select` statement on your server, you change it so it selects only the rows you need, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT $startindex, $numofrows;
```

*Remember to [check for SQL injections](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php13p5.html) of course.*

This way, you only fetch the data you actually want instead of fetching all the data in one go. Remember, your app is on a mobile OS, with a somewhat volatile internet connection sometimes, so if the data you're returning is growing, it wouldn't be nice from a user-perspective to sit and wait for all the data to load, especially when some of it, isn't needed yet.

For instance if you get let's say 1000 rows of data returned, that would take a while to fetch over a mobile internet connection.

After you receive the `JSonObject` with only a limited amount of entries, you can now parse it without keeping track of how many entries are returned.

Inside your Android app, all you need to keep track of is what index in the database, the user has seen so far and then increment this counter every time the user fetches a new page.